# Gremlin queries are not executed in data stax gremlin console

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am trying to run some sample queries from gremlin docs in DataStax Enterprise gremlin console.

```
gremlin> x = [1,2,3]
==>1
==>2
==>3
gremlin> x._().transform{it+1}
No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList._() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), min(), pop(), any(), max(), sum()
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]y
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList._() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), min(), pop(), any(), max(), sum()
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.groovy.plugin.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:188)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:152)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:232)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:481)
gremlin>
```

I want to understand, what version of Gremlin server, Client is used in Datastax enterprise version 5.1?

Why the queries failed.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DSE Graph is not built on TinkerPop 2.x. 2.x is no longer maintained and [GremlinDocs](http://gremlindocs.spmallette.documentup.com/) is only around for reference for legacy applications that still might use it.

DSE Graph supports TinkerPop 3.x - as do most current graph databases. You can find documentation on that here: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/